# pinch-to-zoom on smartphones in front of a large object for Vuforia AR camera

Tags: vuforia

AR detection works best, when the object is fully visible within the camera view.

So when users are in front of larger AR objects, e.g. vending machines, they expect to use pinch-to-zoom to zoom out - instead of walking backwards.

I already searched and only found official information from Vuforia dating back to 2020: https://developer.vuforia.com/comment/74482

Back then, pinch-to-zoom was not supported.

**Is it supported now?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camera zoom is not supported by Vuforia as it will negatively impact tracking performance due to changes in the camera's intrinsic properties, such as focal length.

Comment: Still it is likely possible to create a digital zoom effect by changing the rendering viewport. I am not sure if this can be done in Unity but for Native apps as a developer one has full control of the rendering pipeline.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and kind answer, Dave.

Comment: While that confirms our rough guesses, why this isn't available yet, any improvement would help. 

It doesn't have to be real time pinch-to-zoom. Defining a wider angle ("zoom-out") before the camera opens - in case large objects will be viewed - once at the start would also help.

Comment: However, after some more research I believe to better understand the issue now: 

- even Unity offers no cross-platform wrapping API for camera configuration
- also, I found no way to make that camera configuration persistent/default for other apps - it would be lost, once Vuforia starts the camera again

Comment: Any smart ideas for "zoom-out" are welcome - as this is still tough to convey to users spoiled "by virtually every camera app offering zoom". :)

Thank you all once again!

Comment: You can try to use the set viewport method in Unity https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.CommandBuffer.SetViewport.html